# Problem with Command Pattern under Visual Studio 2008 (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, pointers

I've a problem with this pattern under c++ on VS 2008.
The same code has been tested in gcc (linux, mac and mingw for
widnows) and it works.

I copy/paste the code here:

```
class MyCommand {

public:
    virtual void execute() = 0;
    virtual ~MyCommand () {};
};

class MyOperation {
public:
    virtual void DoIt() {}; //I also write it not inline
};

class MyOperationDerived : public MyOperation {
public:
    virtual void DoIt() {}; //I also write it not inline
};


class MyUndoStackCommand : public MyCommand {
 public:
     typedef void(MyOperation::*Action)();
     MyUndoStackCommand(MyOperation *rec, Action action);
     /*virtual*/ void execute();
     /*virtual*/ ~MyUndoStackCommand();

private:
    MyOperation *myReceiver;
    Action myAction ;
};
```

in cpp:

```
#include "MyUndoStackCommand.h"
#include "MyOperation.h"

MyUndoStackCommand::~MyUndoStackCommand() {
}

MyUndoStackCommand::MyUndoStackCommand(myOperation *rec, Action
action): myReceiver(rec), myAction(action) {
}

void MyUndoStackCommand::execute() {
   ((myReceiver)->*(myAction))();
}
```

use in main.cpp:

```
MyReceiver receiver;
MyUndoStackCommand usc(&receiver, &MyOperation::DoIt);
usc.execute();
```

when I debug under visual studio only if I set inside `MyUndoStackCommand`, directly
`myAction = &MyOperation::DoIt`   , it works, otherwise not.

Any advice?

thank you very much,
dan

**Edit:** The following code compiles with g++ - changes by Neil Butterworth flagged as //NB.

```
class MyCommand {

public:
    virtual void execute() = 0;
    virtual ~MyCommand () {};
};

class MyOperation {
public:
    virtual void DoIt() {}; //I also write it not inline
};

class MyOperationDerived : public MyOperation {
public:
    virtual void DoIt() {}; //I also write it not inline
};


class MyUndoStackCommand : public MyCommand {
 public:
     typedef void(MyOperation::*Action)();
     MyUndoStackCommand(MyOperation *rec, Action action);
     /*virtual*/ void execute();
     /*virtual*/ ~MyUndoStackCommand();

private:
    MyOperation *myReceiver;
    Action myAction ;
};

MyUndoStackCommand::~MyUndoStackCommand() {
}

MyUndoStackCommand::MyUndoStackCommand(MyOperation *rec,  //NB
                                Action action)
    : myReceiver(rec), myAction(action) {
}

void MyUndoStackCommand::execute() {
   ((myReceiver)->*(myAction))();
}

int main() {
    MyOperation receiver;    //NB
    MyUndoStackCommand usc(&receiver, &MyOperation::DoIt);
    usc.execute();
}
```

Comment: I don't see what `MyReceiver` should be (did you mean `MyOperationDerived` )? Also, what is the error message you get?

Comment: Your code as posted does not compile with g++.  I have edited your question to include code that does compile with g++, but I don't have VS - perhaps someone else can test it?

Comment: @Neil: I have tested your edit on VC++ 2008 V9. Works w/o problem.

Answer (score 0):

With Neils edit this works fine in Visual Studio 2008.

```
// command.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>      // added for printing
using namespace std;     // added for printing
class MyCommand {
public:
    virtual void execute() = 0;
    virtual ~MyCommand () {};
};
class MyOperation {
public:
    virtual void DoIt() {
        cout << "myoperation::doit()" << endl;
    }; //I also write it not inline
};
class MyOperationDerived : public MyOperation {
public:
    virtual void DoIt() {
        cout << "myoperationderived::doit()" << endl;
    }; //I also write it not inline
};
class MyUndoStackCommand : public MyCommand {
 public:
     typedef void(MyOperation::*Action)();
     MyUndoStackCommand(MyOperation *rec, Action action);
     /*virtual*/ void execute();
     /*virtual*/ ~MyUndoStackCommand();
private:
    MyOperation *myReceiver;
    Action myAction;
};
// command.cpp
#include "command.h"
MyUndoStackCommand::~MyUndoStackCommand() {
}
MyUndoStackCommand::MyUndoStackCommand(/*m*/ MyOperation *rec, Action
action): myReceiver(rec), myAction(action) {
}
void MyUndoStackCommand::execute() {
   ((myReceiver)->*(myAction))();
}
// main.cpp
#include "command.h"
int main(){ 
 MyOperationDerived receiver;
 MyUndoStackCommand usc(&receiver, &MyOperation::DoIt);
 usc.execute();
}
```

Will print:

```
"myoperationderived::doit()"
```